# AngularjS Oauth 2.0 routing don't catch

Tags: angularjs, oauth, ngroute

I used this code for my Oauth connextion to google :
http://anandsekar.github.io/oauth2-with-angularjs/

but google  retourn uri like this

```
http://localhost:8080/#access_token=xxxx&expires_in=3600
```

but angular route don't catche it :

```
 .when('/**access_token=:accessToken', {
        template:'',
        controller: 'oauthCtrl'
    })
```

How I can do ?

Answer (score 0):

Use just

```
.when('/', {
  template:'',
  controller: 'oauthCtrl'
})
```

and in your `oauthCtrl` inject `$routeParams` then

you can access your query strings by  `$routeParams.access_token` and `$routeParams.expires_in`

Comment: that is ok. When google redirects you to http://localhost:8080/#access_token=xxxx&expires_in=3600 in your login controller access query strings as stated above $routeParams.access_token

Comment: $routeParams.access_token is undefind :(